# Wordpress posts won't display in rows

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm a wordpress newbie and currently working on turning a html website into a template. I want my posts to show up ont op of each other, with always the newest post on top. the content will be filled in using Advanced Custom Fields and the actual text will be displayed in a dropdown submenu when you hit the "read" button.

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

At the moment all the posts will just be displayed in the exact same position, so that they are overlapping. How can I make them show up in seperate rows and also make sure they will slide down to make space for the dropdown?

This is the structure of each post, saved in a content.php file:

```
<div class="post-container">
      <?php $information = get_field('info'); ?>

      <?php if ($information['date']) : ?>
         <div class="contents">
            <li>
               <?php echo $information['date']; ?><br>
               <img src="<?php echo $information['photo']; ?>">
               <br><input id="check03" type="checkbox" name="menu" />
               <p>
                  <?php echo $information['artist']; ?>
                  <br>
                  <i><?php echo $information['exhibition_title']; ?></i>
                  <br>
                  <?php echo $information['venue']; ?>
                  <br> 
                  <?php echo $information['runtime']; ?> 
                  <label for="check03">read</label>

                  <ul class="submenu">
                     <?php echo $information['text']; ?>
                  </ul>
               </p>
            </li>
         </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

this is my stylesheet:

```
.body {
    background-color: #F4F3ED;
    color: darkslategrey;
}

.moon {
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}

.moon img {
    width: 40px;
}

.artwritingaftermidnight {
    margin-right: 4vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1000;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.contents {
    width: 93%;
    position: relative; /* Change to relative to allow for absolute positioning inside */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-style: italic;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contents p {
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: 22px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.contents img {
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    padding-right: 2vw;
}

.contents li {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    overflow: visible;
}

/* Hide the inputs/checkmarks and submenu */
input,
ul.submenu {
    display: none;
}

/* Position the label */
label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 70vw;
    margin-top: -30px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Show the submenu when input is checked */
input:checked~ul.submenu {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-left: -9vw; /* Min value added for better compatibility */
    padding-right: 3vw;
    max-width: 800px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.post-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 20px; /* Adjust the space between posts */
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the HTML that was generated instead of the PHP code that generates it?

Comment: the original html code looks like this

Comment: I wonder what the actual generated HTML code is in your browser when you load the page. I do not have access to your data or your PHP files, so please make sure that your problem can be reproduced by us. In order to do that, you need to share actual HTML without PHP code inside of it. Check the page source in your browser when you load the page and copy the relevant part of the HTML into your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a flex container for your posts with the class .post-container. To make each post show up in a separate row, you are already using flex-direction: column, which is a good start. The gap property is also helpful for adjusting the space between posts.

However, you mentioned that the posts are overlapping. This might be due to the absolute positioning of some elements within each post. In your .contents class, you have set position: relative, which is a good practice for containing absolutely positioned elements.

To ensure that posts don't overlap, you should check the absolute positioning of elements inside the .contents class. Make sure that the elements with absolute positioning are positioned relative to the .contents container.

Here are some suggestions:

**Adjust the absolute positioning:** If you have absolute positioning inside .contents, make sure the positioning is based on .contents. For example:

```
.contents {
    position: relative;
}

.contents .submenu {
    position: absolute;
    /* Add appropriate positioning values */
}
```

**Review margin and padding:** Check if any elements with margins or paddings are affecting the layout. For example, the margin-top: 100px; in .contents might impact the spacing between posts. **Also remove the margins in the negative like(margin-top: -30px;)**

**Check the height of elements:** Ensure that the height of each post is calculated correctly, including the height of the dropdown submenu. If the height is not calculated correctly, it might lead to overlapping.

**Adjust z-index:** If you are using z-index for layering, make sure that higher z-index values are on top.

By addressing these points, you should be able to prevent posts from overlapping and achieve the desired layout with each post in a separate row.